# Validate range inputs are not overlapping

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to validate that two range inputs who filter age do not go over one another. I can't find a way to have it done properly without the sliders behaving erratically, jumping from 0 to 50, and things like that.

I've tried different approaches (pure JS) with similar results:

```
if(input1.value >= input2.value || input2.value <= input1.value){
    input1.value = toString(input2.value - 1);
    input2.value = toString(input1.value + 1);
}
```

This one makes the sliders jump back to 50. I can't remember what else I've tried, but all do sort of the same thing. Either jump back to 50, or the minimumRange jump from 2 or 3 to 100.

I'd rather not use jQuery if at all possible

Here's the fiddle with the whole thing:

[JSfiddle Validation and filters](https://jsfiddle.net/mscola/nhrLtv2c/12/)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't reproduce your issue in your fiddle, but I already see 2 issues in your code:

- if `input1.value` is `"50"`, then `input1.value + 1` will be `"501"`
- `toString()` should be called on numbers: `50.toString()`

So your code should look like:

```
var minEdad = Number(input1.value),
    maxEdad = Number(input2.value);
if(minEdad >= maxEdad) {
    // Decide here what to do, for example
    input1.value = (maxEdad - 1).toString();
}
```

Comment: But what if I want to, in either case, have the slider who's about to overlap to push the other slider up or down?
On another note, the slider jumps straight to 50 when I touch it

Comment: @MartínScola: then you need to handle differently `onchange` on both sliders. Note that this *jump to 50* does not happen with me. I'm using Chrome.

Comment: I'm using Chrome as well. And The only problem I have is with the input1. THe other one works just fine. And it seems that the problem is while going up from 8 to 9 or down from 9 to 8. Both times the slider resets to 50, which isn't even the default value for the slider to begin with

Comment: Never mind, there was something bugging the slider. Your answer fixed the issue!

Answer (score 1):

This is how the function looks like now:

```
function filtroEdad(input1, input2) {
var edadMin = Number(input1.value);
var edadMax = Number(input2.value);

if(edadMin >= edadMax){
    input1.value = (edadMax - 1).toString();
}

if(edadMax <= edadMin){
    input2.value = (edadMin + 1).toString();
}
```

Thank you, @RaphaMex !!